# Google Analytics is not collecting any site speed data

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using the universal tracking code `analytics.js` from Google Analytics.
It has been collecting data and events just fine for multiple years.

However, the site speed section (Behaviour > Site Speed) does not show any data at all. I'm aware that User Timings requires custom calls but Overview, Page Timings and Site Speed Suggestions does not include any measurements at all.
I can see that it has the page views of course but there is no avg. page load time for example.

I've read multiple times that it might be connected to the sampling rate. As I understand it the default is 1%. With more than 50k visitors per day even the default sampling rate should provide enough data. I've since increased the sampling rate like this when creating the tracker: `siteSpeedSampleRate: 10` ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate)).

Furthermore, I've used the GA debugger extension to check whether some kind of timings beacon is actually send to GA. This is the output:

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("create", "UA-XXXXXXXX-X", {cookieDomain: "auto", siteSpeedSampleRate: 10})
analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("require", "displayfeatures")
analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("set", "anonymizeIp", true)
analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("set", "forceSSL", true)
analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("send", "pageView")
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)
```

Comment: are you able to share the site in question?

Comment: Sure! We have multiple domains but e.g. https://www.busradar.com for English speakers or https://www.busliniensuche.de for German

Comment: Hi, I had a look at your site. Looks like how the GA code is put on the page is custom. When I removed it and put in the recommended GA implementation in the header the page timings hits were coming through. Could you do the same? Use the default except for the ga('send') command, this way the tracker is created and globally accessible and in your webpack/analytics.js just reference the global ga() function for pageviews and events.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time @XTOTHEL! I'll try to "standardize" the GA setup and write up a solution here

Comment: @marc did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: @Chris Yes, sorry for not clarifying it back here. Indeed, XTOTHEL identified the problem. Since I've changed it to a standard Google Analytics setup page speed tracking started to work. You can find it in our source code on https://www.busradar.com near the end of the <head> tag.

Comment: Have you tried using gtag.js? I cannot seem to do it with gtag.js

Comment: @bumblebeen We are using the official Google Analytics script. I haven't tried using gtag.js. However, I would assume that given the most up-to-date gtag.js setup and a correct configuration everything should work as expected.